# no puedo mostrar los datos de mongoDB atlas en otros dispositivos

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb, mongoose, mongoatlas

Bueno espero que estés bien. Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una aplicación de noticias cargada en firebase, tengo la base de datos desarrollada en mongoDB, investigando encontré mongodb atlas que lo que hace es generar un enlace para hacer referencia a la base de datos, hasta ahora todo bien, puedo subir y borro y modifico archivos, cuando lo implemento en firebase toma los datos que subí (solo en mi dispositivo), el problema ocurre cuando trato de verlo en otros dispositivos lo intento con varios celulares y nada, alguien sabe por qué lo hace no me lleves datos en otros dispositivos?

adjunto datos.

> mi app noticias of firebase https://nnoticias-3000b.web.app/

> **Mi Back-End**

> index.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = 3700;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://leandro:prueba123@cluster0-shard-00-00.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017/noticias?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-i31fjg-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority').then(() => {

  console.log("Conexion exitosa xd");
    // Creacion del servidor
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Servidor corriendo correctamente en la url: localhost:3700");
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

> mi app.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// archivos de rutas+
var noticias_routes = require('./routes/noticias');
// moddlewares

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json(""));

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

//  rutas
app.use('/api', noticias_routes);

// exportar
module.exports = app;
```

> **Front-End**

> global.ts (tengo la variable de url)

```
  export var Global = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3700/api/'
 };
```

> mi service noticias.service.ts

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Economia, Medicina, Politica, Tecnologia} from '../models/noticias';

import { Global} from './global';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NoticiasService{
  public url: string;

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ){
    this.url = Global.url;
  }

  saveEconomia(economia:Economia): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(economia);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-economia', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getEconomias(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'economias', {headers: headers});
  }

  getEconomia(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'economia/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deleteEconomia(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'economia/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updateEconomia(economia): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(economia);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'economia/'+economia._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }




  savePolitica(politica:Politica): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(politica);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-politica', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getPoliticas(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'politicas', {headers: headers});
  }

  getPolitica(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'politica/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deletePolitica(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'politica/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updatePolitica(politica): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(politica);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'politica/'+politica._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }



  saveMedicina(medicina:Medicina): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(medicina);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-medicina', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getMedicinas(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'medicinas', {headers: headers});
  }

  getMedicina(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'medicina/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deleteMedicina(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'medicina/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updateMedicina(medicina): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(medicina);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'medicina/'+medicina._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }



    saveTecnologia(tecnologia:Tecnologia): Observable<any>{
      let params = JSON.stringify(tecnologia);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

      return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-tecnologia', params, {headers:headers});
    }

    getTecnologias(): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.get(this.url+'tecnologias', {headers: headers});
    }

    getTecnologia(id): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.get(this.url+'tecnologia/'+id, {headers: headers});
    }

    deleteTecnologia(id): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.delete(this.url+'tecnologia/'+id, {headers: headers});
    }

    updateTecnologia(tecnologia): Observable<any>{
      let params = JSON.stringify(tecnologia);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.put(this.url+'tecnologia/'+tecnologia._id, params, {headers: headers});
    }


}
```

**datos extra**

*1. mi backend y mi front están en carpetas separadas*

*2. para ver el contenido que subí a firebase tengo que tener el comando npm start*

*3. Creo que el problema es que nunca dejo el localhost*

Comment: Primero que nada, no deberías estar mostrando los datos de conexión a la base de datos en la publicación, te recomiendo eliminarlos. En mongoDB Atlas, hay un apartado de seguridad de red llamado Network Access. Alli deberias poner la ip del servidor o que se pueda acceder desde cualquier ip (No recomendable)

Comment: hola @Ale , ese cluster va a ser eliminado y sus datos tambien, por lo que lo pongo solo a modo de ejemplo , gracias por la recomendacion, por otro lado no tenia idea de eso , ahora lo chequeo a ver si funciona, muchas gracias por contestar